# Working with multiple input and output files in Python

Tags: file, python

I need to open multiple files (2 input and 2 output files), do complex manipulations on the lines from input files and then append results at the end of 2 output files. I am currently using the following approach:

```
in_1 = open(input_1)
in_2 = open(input_2)
out_1 = open(output_1, "w")
out_2 = open(output_2, "w")

# Read one line from each 'in_' file
# Do many operations on the DNA sequences included in the input files
# Append one line to each 'out_' file

in_1.close()
in_2.close()
out_1.close()
out_2.close()
```

The files are huge (each potentially approaching 1Go, that is why I am reading through these input files one at a time. I am guessing that this is not a very Pythonic way to do things. :)  Would using the following form good?

```
with open("file1") as f1:
    with open("file2") as f2:
        with open("file3") as f3:
            with open("file4") as f4:
                    # Read one line from each 'in_' file
                    # Do many operations on the DNA sequences...
                    # Append one line to each 'out_' file
```

If yes, could I do this while avoiding the highly indented code (commented part, which may itself contain indented lines. Unless, as suggested, I use appropriately defined functions beforehand)? Thanks for the insights!

Comment: Are you also trying to avoid function and class definitions?  A simple function definition would resolve a lot of nesting issues.  Why not use function definitions?

Comment: Also, are you doing some kind of "merge" between the two source files?  Why not have the OS do that for you?  The linux `sort` command will easily combine your two files into a single input stream.

Comment: @S.Lott The files contain genetic data, I am searching for certain patterns, editing them, and writing back the 'corrected' data in the output files. The process is really not straight forward. The 'Do some operations' part of the code is accomplished throught 250 lines of Python code. No way of using quick and dirty Bash commands here :) I am definetly NOT trying to avoid class and function definitions (there are many functions doing small parts of the job, again within the 'Do some operations' section). How do you think I should use a function definition in order to solve the nesting issues?

Comment: Is there a merge?  Or a join?  Or are the two files independent?

Comment: The input files are DNA sequence and a QUALITY sequence files (a score for each letter in the DNA sequence). The operation is neither a merge nor a join. As a result of multiple degenerative and recursive pattern search, I modify the DNA sequence to mark for further edith. At the end, I remove parts of the DNA and also parts of the QUALITY sequence, so that both still match. I also change the name of the sequences. What I call a 'line' in the question really spans many (at least 2) lines, given the format used (FASTA) where one line gives the sequence name and one (or many) give the sequence.

Comment: So it's a relational join between the two sources.  A many-to-many relationship is exploited by this "do many operations..."

Comment: :) I know I left out A LOT of details from the question definition. I am, however, not looking for a better way to solve my DNA file problem (which is accomplished and working), but rather for a more 'pythonic' approach at using multiple files that are opened at the same time. I really hope I do not sound harsh in any way because I am very keen on being showed new, and more pythonic, ways of doing things.This is even more true if they come from people who, evidently, are on a far superior plane of programming knowledge than I am! Cheers

Comment: @Morlock: If you don't specify enough information, you won't get useful answers.  Just because you have something that "works", doesn't really mean much.  I hope I do not sound harsh, but over-simplified questions will lead to over-simplified answers that don't actually solve your actual problem.  Specifically: "avoiding the highly indented code that would result" still makes no sense.  If you have a appropriate function definitions then there's 1 line of "highly indented code".  One.  You only have the problem if your are avoiding function definitions.  But you say you're not.  I'm confused.

Comment: @S.Lott Points taken. And I understand now what you meant with the appropriate function definition (open file1, 2, 3, 4 --appropriate_function-- close files). I think I need to push the 'functional programming' approach further and use it better. Thx

Comment: @Morlock: Defining a function isn't functional programming.  I'm still unclear on what you mean by "avoiding the highly indented code that would result" and "definetly NOT trying to avoid class and function definitions".  I cannot reconcile the two.  Can you please update the question with some clarification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`contextlib.nested()`](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested) allows you to chain multiple context managers in a single statement:

```
with contextlib.nested(open(...), open(...), ...) as (in_1, in_2, ...):
  ....
```

Comment: @Goose Bumper: I've been using Python for 8 years now and I'm *still* learning new things.

Comment: My next step towards improving my Python is DEFINITELY reading the common libraries documentation! Thanks

Comment: Actually, it SHOULD be reading all the SO questions tagged "pythonic" :-)